# JPA many to many Insert

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 3 tables. 1 is parent, 1 is student and one is student_parent. This is a many to many relationship between the parent and student. The parentID is from the parent table and the studentID is from the student table. The student_parent table have studentID, parentID and childRelationship. I need to know how to update the childRelationship field using JPA(hibernate).

Note that I'm using Java Spring with the JPA/Hibernate to update my relational database and that there are several other tables but all I wanted to know was to update childRelationship field.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Student{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "studentID", nullable = false)
private int studentID;


@Column(name="firstName")
private String firstName;   

@Column(name="middleName")
private String middleName;

@Column(name="lastName")
private String lastName;    

@Column(name="validationID")
private String validationID;

@Column(name="birthDate")
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name="gender")
private char gender;

@Column(name="ethnicity")
private String ethnicity;

@Column(name="photo") // character type has to confirmed
private byte[] photo;

@Column(name="gradeLevel")
private int gradeLevel;

@Column(name="rewardPoints")
private String rewardPoints;

@Column(name="dateCreated")
private Date dateCreated;

@Column(name="schoolID")
private Integer schoolID;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressID")
    private Address address;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userName")
    private UserAccount userAccount;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="student_parent",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "studentID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parentID")})
    private Set<Parent> parents = new HashSet<Parent>();


    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="student_community",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "studentID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "communityID")})
    private Set<Community> communities = new HashSet<Community>();



    //getter and setting
```

then the parent.

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Parent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int parentID;   

@Column(name="userName")
private String userName;

@Column(name="firstName")
private String firstName;   

@Column(name="middleName")
private String middleName;

@Column(name="lastName")
private String lastName;    

@Column(name="validationID")
private String validationID;

@Column(name="maritalStatus")
private String maritalStatus;

@Column(name="noOfChildren")
private int noOfChildren;

@Column(name="birthDate")
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name="gender")
private char gender;

@Column(name="ethnicity")
private String ethnicity;

@Column(name="annualIncome")
private Float annualIncome;

@Column(name="dateCreated")
private Date dateCreated;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressID")
    private Address address;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "userName",unique = true, nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private UserAccount userAccount;

//getter and setter
```

Comment: Since you're using JPA, you're using entities. The tables are irrelevant. What we need to know is the code of your entities, what you tried, what you expected it to do, and what it did instead.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an association table, you need to bring it into the entity world as an **association class**. The primary key of the association class is a composite key made of the student id and the parent id. Don't forget to implement hashcode and equals on the primary key class. With this mapping you can gain access to the attributes of the m:n relationships (i.e. the "childRelationship" column). You'll also need to add getters and setters or go with field access.

```
/**
 * Maps to parent table in database
 */
@Entity
class Parent {
    @Id
    long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    Set<Relationship> relationships;
}

/**
 * Maps to student table in database
 */
@Entity
class Student {
    @Id
    long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
    Set<Relationship> relationships;
}

/**
 * Encapsulates primary key in relationship table
 */
class RelationshipId {
    long studentId;
    long parentId;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ((Long)(studentId + parentId)).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null
                && obj instanceof RelationshipId
                && ((RelationshipId)obj).studentId == studentId
                && ((RelationshipId)obj).parentId == parentId;
    }
}

/**
 * Maps to relationship table in database
 */
@Entity
@IdClass(RelationshipId.class)
class Relationship {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent")
    Parent parent;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="student")
    Student student;

    @Column
    String childRelationship;
}
```